# Idomatic QT architecture for simple forms?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, architecture

I am currently working on a medium-sized project that will need to utilize many form-like dialogs. I am developing this application using Qt5 widgets. (I am trying to implement a debugging tool for a class-based network protocol). Most of the logic behind the forms is very simple.

The view for a form would look like this:

[image: An example form]

Basically, when send is pressed it just constructs a packet using the data in the form, and would insert it into the message buffer to be sent out when appropriate later in the program. I want to utilize proper coding idioms when I develop this because I'm using this project to familiarize myself with GUI programming.

What concerns me, is that I don't know how to idiomatically structure my code in a way that is extensible, testable, and robust. I don't want my dialog to be directly responsible for inserting the data into the send stream, nor should it have to handle any business logic associated with it.

Naively I would imagine that the view should do very little logic other than communicate to some other part of the process that the user has edited something or pressed a button, perhaps it could validate that the text is in a proper format. The other part of the process would be what I imagine to be the 'model', therefore (I believe) following an MV architecture. This leads to several questions:

1. Most tutorials like [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) seem to want the user to implement a `QAbstractListModel` or a `QAbstractTableModel`, or perhaps even a `QAbstractItemModel`, but none of these seem needed or relevant to the type of data I am working with, furthermore, their interface seems to be very heavy-handed for what I think is simple data flow -- do I need to subclass one of these in order to properly fulfill the MV architecture or could I just manage the connections myself? If I manage the connections myself, should I create a presenter class to handle this and therefore implement an MVP architecture?
2. How should data be passed from this form to the rest of the application? I would prefer to avoid any/all global/static designs if plausible/correct. On send a packet should be constructed and inserted into the send buffer, but should that be done in the model for this dialog? Should a reference to the buffer or its controlling interface be provided and manipulated by this model? Should the relevant data be passed or returned to some outside model that would handle the buffer manipulation?
3. The data in these forms are basically 1 to 1 with the information needed to construct the messages for the send buffer, to the point that you could reasonably use or adapt the existing interfaces to be a functional model, however, I feel that this would be a code smell -- is that correct? Should I create a new class that basically mirrors my message class in order to have better separation of concerns?

Thank you all for any insight or resources that can be provided. Much of this is me overthinking the problem, but I would like to be sure that my design philosophy is sound before I implement 60+ dialogs so that this application can fully cover the protocol's standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want my dialog to be directly responsible for inserting the data into the send stream

Exactly. And it should only be responsible for passing the data on to some service which is responsible for sending the message i.e., *Separation of concern* and single responsibility.

> Most tutorials like this seem to want the user to implement a QAbstractListModel or a QAbstractTableModel, or perhaps even a QAbstractItemModel, but none of these seem needed or relevant to the type of data I am working with,

Is your data going to be represented in a table / list / tree. If yes, then you can use one of these / subclass them. Alternatively, you can use the `QListWidget` / `QTreeWidget` etc which don't use the model-view design. If no, then these are not for you obviously. It depends on the data and how you want to present it, and only you know about the data so you have to make that decision.

> How should data be passed from this form to the rest of the application?

Using signal / slot mechanism. Take the form in the picture for example. The `send` button above shouldn't send anything. It should just accept the data entered into the form and then pass that data via a signal to some other service for example a MessageSender service or a ValidationService. That is all the form should do.

> I would prefer to avoid any/all global/static designs if plausible/correct.

That is good and you should avoid them unless there is no other way. For example, a logging service is something that is needed everywhere in the program throughout the lifetime of a program, I would make it a singleton.

> On send a packet should be constructed and inserted into the send buffer, but should that be done in the model for this dialog? Should a reference to the buffer or its controlling interface be provided and manipulated by this model?

Use signal / slots. A dialog should just take input, it shouldn't be sending data around or doing other things. It should take input and pass it on. Design your classes / objects with this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for being thorough, I'm still getting used to the QT signal slots mechanisms so I think I might have underestimated their capabilities or when to use them. I'm glad that the overall answer is fairly simple though, thank you.